# Remove part of string between 2 different characters

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my string = `data-dateformat="dd-MMM-YYYY" class="info th-header-bc-ascolor">22-02-2017`

Please note that `dd-MMM-YYYY` can be any dateformat.

What I want is to remove every thing between `data-dateformat="dd-MMM-YYYY"` and `>`

This is my best attempt, but i know it don't work.

`mystring.substring(mystring.indexOf('data-dateformat="*"'), htmlcontent.indexOf('>'));`

How can i solve this?

Comment: You can directly use jQuery method: `.removeClass()` to remove all classes

Comment: Thanks for the coment, But it comes from a string not from an object, It is all loaded from a search query through sharepoint.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> to remove every thing between **data-dateformat="dd-MMM-YYYY"** and **>**

You may try the following approach with [***String.prototype.replace()***](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) function and specific regex pattern:

```js
var str = 'data-dateformat="dd-MMM-YYYY" class="info th-header-bc-ascolor">22-02-2017',
    new_str = str.replace(/(data-dateformat="[^"]+")[^>]+>/, '$1>');

console.log(new_str);
```

`[^"]+` - will match any character except `"`, i.e. `data-dateformat` attribute value(between double quotes)

`[^>]+` - will match any character except `>`

`$1` - points to the first captured group which is `(data-dateformat="[^"]+")`